# Get IP from host in C#

Tags: c#

hi i am wanting to get the ip of a host, the code I found is this:

```
    string howtogeek = "www.google.com";
    IPAddress[] addresslist = Dns.GetHostAddresses(howtogeek);
    foreach (IPAddress theaddress in addresslist)
    {
        test.AppendText(theaddress.ToString() + Environment.NewLine);
    }
```

the problem is that I only get the first IP found without using foreach because I just want the first one, anyone can help me?

Comment: `IPAddress firstOne = addresslist.FirstOrDefault();`

Comment: What do you need the IP address for? Is there a reason why you can't do whatever you're up to with the host name?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could just use:

```
string howtogeek = "www.google.com";
IPAddress[] addresslist = Dns.GetHostAddresses(howtogeek);
var firstIp = addresslist[0];
```

Depending on the framework you are using, you can also use [`Enumerable.FirstOrDefault()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb340482%28v=vs.110%29.aspx).

```
string howtogeek = "www.google.com";
IPAddress[] addresslist = Dns.GetHostAddresses(howtogeek);
var firstIp = addresslist.FirstOrDefault();
```

Answer (score 0):

Normally a machine can have multiple ip addresses. If there is only one network adapter XX there will be at least two ip's: the network adapter XX ip and the loopback 127.0.0.1.
That say, you can use the following code to get the first IP:

```
string howtogeek = "www.google.com";
IPAddress[] addresslist = Dns.GetHostAddresses(howtogeek);
if(addresslist.Lengt > 0){
   test.AppendText(addresslist[0].ToString() + Environment.NewLine);
}
```

Comment: While it's true that every NIC will have at least two addresses including the loopback, you will never see it by using `Dns.GetHostAddresses` as this queries the DNS registration for the IP on a remote machine, and there are better alternatives to getting the local ip address.  Just to be clear, as one should not be concerned about the loopback address

Answer (score 0):

The first IP address will be

```
string howtogeek = "www.google.com";
IPAddress[] addresslist = Dns.GetHostAddresses(howtogeek);
IPAddress firstAddress = addresslist[0];
```